# c# httpclient running into issues - beginner

Tags: c#, sockets, httpclient

I'm running into an issue that I don't really understand. I'm trying to run a script that notifies me whenever a specific term is found on a website.

For most of the websites webClient class is working, however on other websites like https://amd.com I have to use the httpClient class.

If I do a loop with a httpClient request like this:

```
while(true)
{
   if (erfolg4 == 0)
            {
                
                try
                {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.TryParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1");
                    httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
                    string htmlCode = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://www.amd.com/de/direct-buy/5450881500/de");                        
                    httpClient.Dispose();

                    if (htmlCode.Contains("Out of stock"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("cpu not available");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("found");
                        SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(@"c:\Windows\Media\test.wav");
                        simpleSound.Play();
                        erfolg4 = 1;
                        EmailSend("AMD CPU");
                        await Task.Delay(20000);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("error amd cpu");
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
                                    
            }
}
```

it keeps running into an timeout exception every second time. If I run multiple instances of this program, it still fails every second time the loop runs through (both loops are independend however).

If I want to search for another term on a subdomain of https://amd.com it always fails. As if there was still a socket open that would prevent any other connection.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Repeating the loop will not solve the timeout issue because each time you are starting from the beginning.  You need to increase the timeout.

Comment: It will always run into a timeout (whether it is 2 seconds or 2 minutes) if it loads the website for the second time.

so the pattern looks like this: request amd (success) - loop restarts - request amd (fails) - restart loop - request amd (success) -  restart loop - request amd (fail)

Comment: Without forensically inspecting your code. Its possible the site is just throttling you.

Comment: I was thinking the same but how does it explain the fact that I can run 2 instances of the program simultaneously and the fail/success pattern is identical. Or why doesn't it help at all if I set a Task.Delay ? Right now it has to fail once in order to succeed

Comment: There is nothing that immediately sticks out as the problem given what you explain. The first thing i would do is use something like Fiddler to check the calls and responses, even with a browser

Comment: Not all websites are the same.  There are lots of factors where the above code will fail.  There are issues with authentication. proxy, certificates, headers, ids, properties.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the HttpClient documentation:

"HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application. Instantiating an HttpClient class for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads. This will result in SocketException errors."

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0

If you create the instance of the client before the loop, do you still get the exceptions?

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
while(true)
{
   if (erfolg4 == 0)
            {
                
                try
                {
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.TryParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 14_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1");
                    httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
                    string htmlCode = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://www.amd.com/de/direct-buy/5450881500/de");

                    if (htmlCode.Contains("Out of stock"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("cpu not available");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("found");
                        SoundPlayer simpleSound = new SoundPlayer(@"c:\Windows\Media\test.wav");
                        simpleSound.Play();
                        erfolg4 = 1;
                        EmailSend("AMD CPU");
                        await Task.Delay(20000);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("error amd cpu");
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
                                    
            }
}
httpClient.Dispose();
```

Comment: Although good advice, Its unclear to me how this would fix the immediate problem.

Comment: Yes I tried it aswell but the outcome is identical.

Comment: True, sorry, I might have been a bit hasty with sending an answer. Will think it through better!